# Choosing the right correlation test for the given variables

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, correlation

I need to choose between Pearson, Spearman and Kendall's tau correlations for the given varibles $A$ and $B$:

1. $A,B$ are continuous with importance to value
2. $A,B$ are ordinal variables
3. $A$ is continuous and $B$ is ordinal
4. $A,B$ are continuous with importance to order

My try:

1. The only correlation test which uses *values* is **Pearson**.
2. It seems to me that **Kendall's tau** best fits though Spearman could be used as well.
3. I've understood that **Spearman** is good for both continuous and ordinal, but technically we could use Kendall's tau, can't we?
4. **Kendall's tau** - since the order is important

So as you can see I'm somewhat confused regarding choosing the right test and I'd be glad if you could help me understand what are the appropriate choices.

Thanks

Comment: This would be better to ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com I would think

Comment: @GEdgar: Maybe so, but we _do_ have a (statistics) tag on this site, which is not entirely futile.

Comment: For 4, I'd prefer Spearman. Order is important, but not necessarily looking for _linear_ association, which depends on values. For 3, see [_this Wikipedia page_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient).

Comment: @BruceET, regarding (4): It is claimed that order *is* important, so wouldn't it be Kendall's tau after all?

Comment: I'm still confused of (2), (3) though. Both Kendall's tau and Spearman are non-parametric, so why would I prefer one over the other? (in the context of the question of course)

Comment: Consider $x = (1,2,3,4,5); y =(1,4,9,16,25).$ Spearman correl. is 1; Pearson correlation not 1. Perfect association since $y = x^2$, but the association is not perfectly _linear._ Pearson measures linear component of association. Consider $x = (1,2,3,4,5); z = (2,4,6,8,10)$. Both Pearson and Spearman give correl. 1. // I have used Kendall mainly for ordinal categorical data, and not sure what your text says about it. Some texts want it used for _everything_ categor.

Comment: This looks to me like an exercise for which you are supposed to parrot back language lurking in the foregoing section or chapter. I suggest you read carefully and parrot faithfully. // In my experience, brief informal and generic statements such as these are _always_ wrong when put to the test on material the author did not anticipate. (They are often made by people with more pedagogical experience than practical statistical experience.) You are likely to get a variety of opinions from competent practicing statistician. // Wikipedia on 'Kendall tau' is strong on fact, short on opinion.